# regarding setting up ogrid and fillup the corresponding multidimensional array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand the following Python segment.

```
def upsample_filt(size):
    factor = (size + 1) // 2
    if size % 2 == 1:
        center = factor - 1
    else:
        center = factor - 0.5
    og = np.ogrid[:size, :size]
    return (1 - abs(og[0] - center) / factor) * \
           (1 - abs(og[1] - center) / factor)
```

According to `numpy`, `ogrid returns a mesh-grid ndarrys with only one dimension.I think the program want to generate`size*size`array. Why is it be written as`og = np.ogrid[:size, :size]`Or what does`:size` mean?

As a test, I setup `size=4`, and `print((1 - abs(og[0] - center) / factor)*(1 - abs(og[1] - center) / factor))`, the output is as follows:

```
[[ 0.0625  0.1875  0.1875  0.0625]
 [ 0.1875  0.5625  0.5625  0.1875]
 [ 0.1875  0.5625  0.5625  0.1875]
 [ 0.0625  0.1875  0.1875  0.0625]]
```

I am not very clear how does `(1 - abs(og[0] - center) / factor)*(1 - abs(og[1] - center) / factor)` fillup this multi-dimensional array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets make it simpler:

```
In [264]: og=np.ogrid[:3,:2]
In [265]: og
Out[265]: 
[array([[0],
        [1],
        [2]]), array([[0, 1]])]
```

The shape of these 2 is `(3,1)` and `(1,2)`.  They are 2d; 'o' for 'open'.

```
In [266]: og[0]*og[1]
Out[266]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2]])
```

They broadcast together to form a (3,2) array

(3,1), (1,2) => (3,2), (3,2) => (3,2)

Look at what `mgrid` produces:

```
In [271]: np.mgrid[:3,:2]
Out[271]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [2, 2]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1]]])
```

2 (3,2) arrays, that produce the same combination

`ogrid` and `mgrid` are class objects with unique indexing method.  `[:3, :2]` looks to Python as regular indexing.

`meshgrid` produces the same thing, but with a regular function syntax

```
In [275]: np.meshgrid(np.arange(3), np.arange(2),sparse=True,indexing='ij')
Out[275]: 
[array([[0],
        [1],
        [2]]), array([[0, 1]])]
```

Another way of performing the same calculation - by using `[:,None]` to turn the 1st range into a (3,1) array.  Here the broadcasting is (3,1),(2,) => (3,1),(1,2) => (3,2)

```
In [276]: np.arange(3)[:,None]*np.arange(2)
Out[276]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 2]])
```

===================

```
(1 - abs(og[0] - center) / factor) *
(1 - abs(og[1] - center) / factor)
```

this just scales the 2 ranges and them multiplies them together

```
In [292]: a=(1-abs(np.arange(4)-1.5)/2)
In [293]: a[:,None]*a
Out[293]: 
array([[ 0.0625,  0.1875,  0.1875,  0.0625],
       [ 0.1875,  0.5625,  0.5625,  0.1875],
       [ 0.1875,  0.5625,  0.5625,  0.1875],
       [ 0.0625,  0.1875,  0.1875,  0.0625]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.